# How to use go-routines while parsing text file for URLs with regex

Tags: regex, go, slice, goroutine, waitgroup

I've been given a task to search for URLs in text file useng regex and goroutines with waitgroup in the way the given way: text should be devided between N workers (goroutines), each goroutine search for //https://, goroutines in waitgroup, final result should be a slice of strings (URLs) from all goroutines together.

Iam wotking with a txt.file with dozens of stuff in a single string but including URLs
right for now i know how to extract a slice of URLs from the text but without deviding a text and goroutines...

`````
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func Parser1(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    time.Sleep((1 * time.Second))
    b, err := os.ReadFile("repitations")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    str := string(b)

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:https?://)?(?:[^/.]+\.)*google\.com(?:/[^/\s]+)*/?`)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindAllString(str, -1))
    wg.Done()
}

func Parser2(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    time.Sleep((1 * time.Second))
    b, err := os.ReadFile("repitations")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    str := string(b)

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:https?://)?(?:[^/.]+\.)*google\.com(?:/[^/\s]+)*/?`)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindAllString(str, -1))
    wg.Done()
}
func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go Parser1(&wg)
    go Parser2(&wg)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Well done!")
}````
`````

Comment: My next step was introducing 2 goroutinies but in result i have 2 same slices...

Answer (score 0):

Split your read process.
Open file with os.Open() and read sequentially with file.ReadAt().
Pass length to read and offset from start to Parser()

```
func Parser(wg *sync.WaitGroup, f *os.File, length int64, offset int64) {
    defer wg.Done()
    content := make([]byte, length)
    _, err := f.ReadAt(content, offset)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%s", content)
    ....
}
```

Comment: So how should i devide the text into parts to pars it individually?

Comment: @Raptorik you can get the file length, create goroutines with length split across them and calculate the offset to read the file from. You can use for loop for this purpose.

Comment: can you show me it in the code?
I can share with you what I have for now if it will help_